# Unable to access my Swift Package from GitLab

Tags: swift, gitlab, swift-package-manager, xcode13

**Environment:**  
Xcode Version 13.0 beta 4 (13A5201i)

 Mac OS Big Sur (11.5) on Mac M1 Mini

**Note:** This may be a Xcode bug.

**Goal:** To access my custom swift package from GitLab. 
**Problem:** No packages identified on Gitlab.

**Steps:**

1. Create a Swift Package with version tag ('1.0.0' or whatever) per standard procedure.
2. Push package into a GitLab account.
3. Creat a simple iOS app.to use the custom Swift package just made.
4. Try to Add your package to this app. (Select 'Add Package' under the File menu.)
5. I found there are no such packages on GitLab.  **Why???**

Here's my package with a couple of version tags. 
I've change the branch name from 'main' to 'master'. 
Notice the local & remote branches are in sync (as seen via Xcode).

[image]

**Gitlab via Browser:** However, the remote (GitHub) server refuses to have the origin 'main' branch removed:

[image]

Select 'Add Package' under the File menu. 
  *There's no package listed in GitLab:*

[image]

Why don't I see my Swift Package on GitLab? 
What am I missing; or doing wrong??

Also, is either a 'master' or 'main' branch required to work between remote & local package within Xcode or can any name be used as the sole branch?